# I am getting an Assertion error but when i write a cout statement it goes away

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting an Assertion error but when i write a cout statement it goes away.

Error:

> a.out: malloc.c:2427: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
>   (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
>   prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
>   0)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

When I comment in the cout statement in the main it works fine.

Output:
   helloSort Successful.

Here the code link:
https://pastebin.com/ULNZ8RyH

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

/*
Create a randomly shuffled array with distinct of size (size), containing value sfrom 0 to size-1.

Input:
    size: (int) size of the array

Return Value:
    vector<int> : A vector of ints with size (size).
*/
vector<int> createArrayDistinct(int size)
{
    vector<int> array(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    random_shuffle(array.begin(), array.end());
    return array;
}

vector<int> counting_sort_v1(vector<int> array, int K){

    int N = array.size();
    vector<int> pos(N);
    vector<int> output(N);

    for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++)
    {
        pos[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        pos[array[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        if(i)
            pos[i] = pos[i] + pos[i-1];
    }

    for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[pos[array[i]]] = array[i];
        pos[array[i]]--;
    }
    return output;
}

vector<int> counting_sort_v2(vector<int> array, int K){

    int N = array.size();
    vector<int> pos(N);
    vector<int> output(N);

    for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++)
    {
        pos[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        pos[array[i]]++;
    }

    int sum = N;
    for(int i = K-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        pos[i] = sum - pos[i];
        sum = pos[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        output[pos[array[i]]] = array[i];
        pos[array[i]]++;
    }
    return output;
}

bool check_sort(vector<int> array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > array[i+1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int size =  10;
    //cin>>size;

    vector<int> array = createArrayDistinct(size);
    //cout<<"hello";
    vector<int> output = counting_sort_v1(array,size);
    if(check_sort(output))
        cout<<"Sort Successful.";
    else
        cout<<"Sort Unsuccessful.";
}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ps, your code is not minimal and I suspect a array out of bounds access. Try to run that program with valgrind

Answer (score 1):

in `counting_sort_v2` function 
You Reach to the following loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < K; i++)
{
    if(i)
        pos[i] = pos[i] + pos[i-1];
}
```

with `pos`: (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

after the loop pos is: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

So in the last loop `output[pos[array[i]]]` for the last element of `pos` (10) will fall out of the vector bounderies.